# Varieties not injecting into liftable ones

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I give you a finite field $F$. Can you give me an example of a geometrically connected smooth proper $F$-scheme $X$ such that there is no monomorphism (in the category of $F$-schemes) $X\rightarrow X'$ such that there is a smooth $W(F)$-scheme whose special fiber is $X'$?

Comment: This is probably not known. I can imagine adapting Hironaka's non-projective example to characteristic $p$ by taking e.g. all $\mathbf{F}_p$-rational lines in $\mathbf{P}^3$ and blowing them up in different order on different opens. This should be non-projective and non-liftable, but I have no idea why it should not embed in something liftable.